# Postgresql COUNT() on distinct composite PK

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there any way to call **count** on a distinct composite PK with Postgres? I am getting the following error and do not know why.

```
SQL: SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: function count(character varying, integer) does not exist LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "t".id, "t".library_id) FROM "ab_colle... ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

EDIT:

The query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "t".id, "t".library_id) 
  FROM "ab_collection" "t" 
 WHERE t.library_id=1
```

EDIT:

I should also note that it is a core framework (Yii) method which generates this code and I cannot edit it but I need to be sure whether I am doing something wrong or not before I try to find a workaround.

Comment: Show us your actual SQL query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ROW("t".id, "t".library_id))
  FROM "ab_collection" "t" 
 WHERE t.library_id=1
```

from here https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/3004#issuecomment-27601733

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use `COUNT(col1, col2,...)`. This would need to be two seperate like `COUNT(col1), COUNT(col2)`. I don't think it will therefore work on a composite key.

> ...count(character varying, integer) does not exist...

Tells you simply you cannot use the function because it's invalid (though the syntax is correct)

But since you are using a composite PK, how about

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from table WHERE pk1 = XXX AND pk2 = YYY;
```

Comment: I know the count(*) approach would work, but it is a core framework method which generates this code and I cannot edit it. It strikes me weird that it breaks in the first place to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate two columns

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ("t".id||' '||"t".library_id)) 
  FROM "ab_collection" "t" 
 WHERE t.library_id=1
```